# Help identifying small urban tree

Tags: identification, trees

Can anyone help me identify the following tree?

Any help would be gratefully received.

*Note: I do not have further images available for this tree, hopefully it can be identified from the images below.*

Thanks!

[image: Tree]

Answer (score 4):

I'm not in total agreement again - its an Acer, but I think its Acer rubrum rather than campestre, judging by what I can see of the leaf shape, which seems more pointed than those on campestre, the shape of the tree overall, and colour of the bark. Also the red leaf tips just beginning to appear as the tree autumns - most of the leaves should go a good red before finally falling, whereas A. campestre tends to go tan/brown/golden colours.

Comment: You could be right, hard to tell without more closeup's of the underside of the leaf or the samara's

Comment: For sure, but no more photos/info available, apparently...its those red leaf tips that made me look harder at it...

Comment: I have to agree. I was going to say Swamp Maple which is how I know this species, and I based this on the denser but floppy appearance of the leaves. And yes the yellowing on the leaves is not fall color, that's a magnesium or manganese deficiency.  It could also be an iron deficiency however, iron is needed for plants to use most other nutrients. Best to get your soil analyzed at your closest agricultural extension office. If it's iron deficient, you can throw down other nutrients and it appears not to do much at all.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is the hedge maple or field maple or [acer campestre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_campestre) on the basis of the leaves, small size and general growth habit.  The species has a wide range of shapes for the leaves as can be seen in [this reference](http://classes.hortla.wsu.edu/hort231/List04/AcerCamp.html).

It is native to Europe but widely used across the world, particularly in North America where it has naturalized.  There are over thirty different cultivars which select for smaller size, better shape and resistance to mildew, canker and wilt.

It is popular as an urban tree because of it's tolerance of shade, slow growth and relatively small mature size in urban environments of ~ fifty feet.

As a point of interest I see an [Iron/manganese deficiency](http://www.mgofmc.org/docs/nutrientdeficiency.pdf) developing in the lower leaves where the veins are green but the rest of the leaf is yellowing.  This is probably due to a soil pH over 7, or alkaline, which is typical of limestone based clay soils.